# Memory usage Task Manager

Tags: windows, memory, opera

Task Manager is stuck in it's performance measurements. It won't update from the point I get when I boot it up: [image: starting]

In addition to that Youtube video's break due to exceeding memory. So that's why I'm looking at the memory in the first place.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: You have 35GB of committed memory *on boot*? What are you running?

Comment: I would also suggest to run some deep antivirus scans by at least your installed product and [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).